# Azure Data Transfer from Remote Data Center

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, file-transfer

Currently I have a Powershell script running on a VM (not on Azure) using NEW-PS Drive and the server credentials to do a database transfer:

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject] @(
  Write - Output "Timestamp: $(Get-Date -Format u)"
  @ {
    db = "DB1";
    source = "\\XXX.XXX.X.XXX\DatbaseFolder\DatabaseBackup";
    username = "domain1\username1";
    password = "password1"
  },
  @ {
    db = "DB2";
    source = "\\http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/\DatabaseBackup";
    username = "domain2\username2";
    password = "password2"
  })
foreach($i in $obj) {
  $pw = $i.password | ConvertTo - SecureString - AsPlainText - Force
  $cred = New - Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($i.username, $pw)
  New - PSDrive - Name P - PSProvider FileSystem - Credential $cred - Root $i.source
  $backup_latest = Get - ChildItem - Path P: -Filter "*.bak" | Sort - Object LastWriteTime - Descending | Select - Object - First 1
  Write - Output $backup_latest
  if ($backup_latest.Exists) {
    Copy - Item - Path $backup_latest.FullName - Destination(E: \BACKUP\ + $i.db) - Force
  }
  Remove - PSDrive - Name P
}
```

We are moving our current VM setup to Azure and would like to use something similar that, instead of moves these files to the local machine, copies them to Azure Blob or file storage that we then source from that VM using AZCopy or some other Azure Data Transfer method.

I'm just a bit lost on the best method for getting the data from those remote data locations in a data center in Arizona.

What would be the fastest and most effective method for either rewriting a daily script that runs to transfer these DBs to blob storage or file storage.

Azure beginner here, so please don't be brutal.

Comment: If just moving DBs to blob storage or file storage, you'd better use azcopy which provides a high performance.

Comment: Thats one of the things I am having problems finding out. I can't figure out how to get AzCopy to work with username/password credentials for that remote server/data center.

Comment: can you log into the remote server, then run azcopy directly?